# A Unified, Global Bronze Age, How It Would Affect America

Tags: alternate-history, culture, trade, bronze-age

Here are the points of departure to this scenario:

1. China, not Southwestern Asia, began the Bronze Age in 3300 BCE
2. Either China or the nearby steppes of Central Asia, not Eastern Europe, was the source of horse domestication some 6,000 years ago
3. None of the latest Pleistocene equids (like the Western horse) or camelids (like *Camelops* or *Hemiauchenia*) went extinct
4. The "Chinese Bronze Age" tied (at least most of) the world together with a Silk Trade Network spanning not just China but also the rest of Mainland Asia, Europe, the very thin habitable coastline of North Africa (can't imagine them expanding any farther than the Nile) and the Americas.

How would this "global Bronze Age Silk Trade" affect the peoples of the Americas?  Would they expand their cultures and other ways of living onto other lands?  Or would they end up getting enslaved like their descendants would in our timeline?

Comment: Interesting speculation this might provoke, but isn't it the perfect exemplar of story-based/opinion-based?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. No.

Comment: Questions about how would some large world spanning event affect a society are too broad for this site.

Comment: Point 3 would not have a serious impact as all that would have done is kept more large animals to hunt. It is not likely that those would have been domesticated by the people of the Americas. Without them being domesticated, they would not have any cultural impact (except in adding some more recipes to the cookbook).

Comment: boosting technology in the Americas by several thousand years will make it unrecognizable and all but unpredictable. Bronze smelting was not invented in the Americas until more than 3000 years after Eurasia. and due to geography spread much slower.

Answer (score 1):

1. *China, not Southwestern Asia, began the Bronze Age in 3300 BCE.*

   There no polity recognizable as China in the time frame associated with the Mediterranean Bronze Age. If you mean China in a purely geographic sense, then this assertion is actually not all that far from real history; the oldest bronze objects found in geographical China belong to the [Majiayao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majiayao_culture) culture, and are dated to the early 3rd millennium BCE.

   So yes, they could very well have had bronze in some localities in was in today called China during the late 4th millennium BCE.
2. *Either China or the nearby steppes of Central Asia, not Eastern Europe, was the source of horse domestication some 6,000 years ago.*

   Eastern Europe has nothing to do with the domestication of the horse. (OK, *maybe* the very easternmost fringes of geographical Europe.) As far as anybody knows, the horse was domesticated somewhere on the Eurasian steppe, most likely somewhere in what is today southern Russia or northern Kazakhstan, definitely east of the Urals. That's northern central Asia. The [Sintashta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintashta) and [Botai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botai_culture) cultures are strong candidates.
3. *None of the latest Pleistocene equids (like the Western horse) or camelids (like* Camelops *or* Hemiauchenia*)* *went extinct.*

   Wow, that is one *massive* change.

   *Massive.*

   Whatever happens afterwards will have no relationship whatsoever with real history in the Americas. Which is to say, anything and everything may happen after introducing such a massive change.
4. *The "Chinese Bronze Age" tied (at least most of) the world together with a Silk Trade Network spanning not just China but also the rest of Mainland Asia, Europe,* [...] *North Africa and the Americas.*

   With Bronze Age technology? How did they do that with horse-drawn chariots? Are we to suppose that in addition of creating a large empire (which they didn't), and in addition of having domestic horses (which they didn't), those ancient precursors of the Chinese peoples *also* had workable ocean-going ships? Because they really did not. In fact, the roots of the Chinese culture are inland, not anywhere near the sea.

   As I have said, there were at least *some* places in what is today called China which had bronze metallurgy in the relevant time frame; but sadly there was no such world-spanning trade network. And what on Earth did they trade over such long distances? Remember that even when trade really started in earnest between China and Europe through India, the trade items were luxury goods, not everyday staples. The first trade network carrying bulk goods between India and Europe was established in the *Renaissance* (late 15th, early 16th century CE). (And China is much further east than India.) It may seem surprising, but before the 20th century the various empires which ruled the territory of modern China over the ages never engaged in high-volume trade with the rest of the world.

Comment: Note: long distance trade does not require empires, or wheels.. it existed long before a bronze or copper age started. Danish red flint was transported all over Europe in Neolithic times. There are French finds.. https://www.ub.edu/ubtv/en/video/the-export-of-heligoland-flint-in-prehistory-with-special-focus-on-danish-finds-klaus-hirsch and even British finds https://stephenkuta.com/n242-neolithic-red-heligoland-flint-british-find/

Comment: @Goodies: Yes, we all know that. Low-volume trade can be done on foot; and it may even have a significant impact on culture, for example if the low-volume trade includes the Buddhist books brought on his back by Xuanzang from India as a result of his [*Journey to the West*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_West). On the other hand, civilization changing high-volume trade absolutely requires ships (or, in very modern times, motor-powered wheels) and a political structure capable to enable the required productivity.

Comment: AlexP ships took over much later. The (real world) Silk Route already commenced in the classic period. The silk trade was not small scale, silk became popular everywhere, with Persia as the gateway. The above scenario shifts the Silk Route a few thousand years into the past.

Comment: @Goodies: The classical world traded with India (and with China through India) by sea since the late 4th or early 3rd century BCE. The overland route started being used to connect China with the Mediterranean world much later, late 1st century BCE or even 1st century CE. The sea trade carried by far the largest volume of goods, up to the 7th century CE when the Arabs conquered Egypt and blocked the trade. See [Barbaricum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarikon), modern-day Karachi.

Answer (score 1):

This question raises a subsequent question: if this trade empire existed up into near modern times, would it have allowed the spice trade network to exist? Most of European trade expansion in the 1400's was due to the demand for spices, not silk, and the enormous profits that trading spices brought. Later, the demand on China was for tea, not silk. So, this trade network might have prevented much of modern empire building. How would that have affected the modern world?

You could speculate that the spice trade didn't happen. At which point, one could even doubt if the Americas would have been invaded in the 1500's. England would have found some place else to dump excess population.

This question is way too wide for easy answer on a forum such as this. Write a compelling human story with those assumptions and let the reader figure stuff like this out.

Answer (score 0):

Agree for a large part with David R.. For lack of space and time I've worked out my comment into below answer. The author will have to figure it out.. but I agree this whole thing is more like a "brainstorm" than an actual WB question.

Interesting subject though..

**Roman history could have been cut in half**

The scenario results in a long term dominance of China, maybe that would have caused Mongol, Carpatian and Caucasian people to migrate west in a much earlier stage. The Romans would have had to cope with them in Republican times ? Instead of their 3th-4th century emperors ? Would there have been a Roman empire ? Would Christianity have had a chance to develop in Europe, without a Constantinian era ?

Comment: The Romans *did* cope with barbarian invasions in Republican times. The [sacred geese of Juno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juno_(mythology)#Juno_Moneta) against [Brennus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brennus_(4th_century_BC)) *"[Vae Victis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vae_victis)"* the Gaul, [Marius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaius_Marius) against the [Cimbri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cimbri) and the [Teutons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teutons)...

Comment: Coped indeed.. but they were not *overrun*, like it happened in the 3th-5th century ! When *that* would have started 1000 years earlier, chance we would never had a Ceasar.. or a Nero.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Migration_Period